# Boto3 Error in python2.7 but works in 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, python-3.5, boto3

So I'm using boto3 to access a s3 service. When I use this code it works fine with python3.5 but throws this exception in 2.7, why? I would like to implement it with 2.7 because my whole project is based on 2.7.

```
import boto3

conn = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='eu-west-1', endpoint_url=HOST, aws_access_key_id=KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)

conn.create_bucket(Bucket="pqlamy194762123")
```

With 2.7 this exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3connector.py", line 22, in <module>
    s.createBucket('pqlamy1947621234')
  File "s3connector.py", line 15, in createBucket
    self.s3.create_bucket(Bucket=name ,CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'})
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 170, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/home/elk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error message it doesn't seem to be an issue related specifically to the python version, as Boto3 supports Python 2.7 out of the box. So I made a quick checklist that may (or not) help you find the cause of your problem

- Have you tried both versions of Python under the same environment? `104` errors can have a variety of sources, including networking and server-side temporary issues.
- Are you using a stable version of `boto3`? Try using the latest stable version (`1.4.4` as I'm writing this)
- If the previous doesn't work, try using a previous stable version. Some times these bugs with legacy environments are introduced with newer releases.
- If none of it works, try filing a bug. The boto team is partially supported by Amazon and responds quite quickly to app-breaking issues.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I testet both versions in the same environment (locally on my VM). 

I'm using Version 1.4.4 in both 2.7 and 3.5

I'll try a different version to see if thats the problem